# Interpretation question about the article "Finite mixture modeling of censored data using the multivariate Student-t distribution"

Tags: interpretation, missing-data, likelihood, censoring

I am reading this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X1730310X) and I am struggling to understand the following passage from page 6:
\begin{align*}
L_{i}(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\textbf{V}_{i},\textbf{C}_{i}) = f(\textbf{V}_{i}|\textbf{C}_{i},\boldsymbol{\theta}) = f(\textbf{y}^{c}_{i}\leq\textbf{V}^{c}_{i}|\textbf{y}^{o}_{i},\boldsymbol{\theta})f(\textbf{y}^{o}_{i}|\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \ldots
\end{align*}
To be more precise, I do not know how to justify the two equalities in question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should define the terms for us, as people generally don't like answering questions where they have to click through to an article to understand the question...